# How to store an API token in a variable using JMeter

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am very new to Jmeter and just started to work on it. I have a scenari, below are the input details.

Scenario:

1. Login to the application using microsoft credentials (API No.1)
2. Navigate to Customer search page
3. Select the value say Search 'By name' (By name is an API No.2)
4. Click search
5. Results will be displayed

Step 1 API I was able to do it successfully, since I followed some videos in the internet.
But for the application related API (By name), I am able to do it for the current session but not for all the session.

**By name API I am passing in the 'Body Data' of 'HTTP Request' as**

{"branch":null,"agent":{"code":"00092","type":null,"name":"SOVQOSTOVJT OSJOTWW","unit":{"code":"A0102","name":"OJTVWXSKSVVKJ  JVSXVJXS","unitHead":null},"branch":{"code":"A0100","name":"SXTJV","channel":null},"rank":{"code":"BM","description":"Senior Director"},"emailAddress":"mt_mls_bm1@mlsg.onmicrosoft.com","status":{"code":"01","description":"Active"},"candidate":{"number":"14000350","name":"SOVQOSTOVJT OSJOTWW","dob":"1956-04-25"},"originalAgentCode":"000092"},"searchBy":"P","nameSearchParam":{"customerName":null,"idNo":null},"policySearchParam":{"policyNo":"14708787"},"policyStatusSearchParam":{"policyStatus":null,"startDate":null,"endDate":null,"daysLeftBeforeExpiry":null},"policyByServiceTrackingSearchParam":{"customerName":null,"policyNo":null,"idNo":null,"customerStatus":null,"recievedDateBST":{"begin":"2021-06-26T","end":"2021-08-26T"}},"policyByPremiumSearchParam":{},"policyByUnsuccess":{},"unit":null}

**HTTP Header Manager**

[image]

**JSON Extractor**

[image]

The problem is, if you see the 2 token values 'manutouch_token' and 'X-Auth-Token' these are dynamic values. When i am in current session this will have these values, after logout  new values will be generated. I want to store these token values somewhere and pass it or some part of the token need to be extracted. I don't know how to do this process. I have no idea at all. Can someone help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably these tokens are returned somewhere in the login process, you need to carefully inspect all the responses (pay attention to literally everything: response body, [response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header), response [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) especially in case of [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)) - the tokens should be there.

Once you figure out where do they live you should be able to extract them using suitable [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), well configured Post-Processor will extract the token from the response and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and you will be able to replace recorded values with the dynamic variables containing actual tokens.

See [Using Regular Expressions to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables) article for example implementation (use it as a reference only, not as the guide as your application details might be different), the key point is implementing the [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) for each and every dynamic parameter in your test scenario

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri T. I was able to get the solution for this...Finally i found those tokens and stored them in a variable.